# Confused about Istio ServiceRoleBinding user

Tags: kubernetes, istio

```
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRole
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - services: ["httpbin.default.svc.cluster.local"]
    methods: ["GET"]
---
apiVersion: "rbac.istio.io/v1alpha1"
kind: ServiceRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: myservice
  namespace: default
spec:
  subjects:
  - user: "cluster.local/ns/default/sa/default"
  - user: "default"
  roleRef:
    kind: ServiceRole
    name: "myservice"
```

I have `myservice` -> `myapp` where `myapp` pod uses `ServiceAccount` `default`.

```
kubectl get pod myapp-8994abf23f-75vtk -o yaml | grep service      
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
    - --serviceCluster
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
```

I would expect if I exec into `myapp` pod which uses `myservice`, to be able to `curl http://httpbin:8000/headers` service, but I still get `RBAC: access denied`. It only works with `user: "*"`.

What am I supposed to put for `user`?

Comment: If you do `kubectl get serviceaccounts default -o yaml` everything is correct?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes. ```kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-08-17T20:19:07Z"
  name: default
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "415"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/serviceaccounts/default```

Comment: You can try to [debug authorization](https://istio.io/docs/ops/security/debugging-authorization/), also not sure if you read [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authz-http/)